# Create IList of objects in class - fill listview in form

Tags: c#, listview, ilist

We have been given an example of using an IList which is used to fill a list box. I would like to use the same process to fill the list with objects but to fill a ListView.

The code from the object class looks like this:

```
public void ListClients(IList list)
{
    list.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CLIENTS; ++i)
    {
        if (myClients[i] == null)
            continue;
        list.Add(myClients[i].FullName);
    }
}
```

the code in the form, like this:

```
private void ListClientButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CDB.ListClients(ListClientsBox.Items);
}
```

I have tried numerous ways but I guess that I don't understand the IList concept well enough. Is it possible to fill a listview in Details view from the IList?

Comment: Yes ListView.Items also implements the contract IList. So it should be substitutable in your ListClients method. IList is just a contract that any class that wishes to be used as an IList must implement. e.g. ListViewItemCollection http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: I have tried that but in the listview on the form it only places the object name in the first column

Answer (score 2):

Does your `ListView` control have any columns set? If it doesn't, content won't be visible. Try:

```
private void ListClientButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListClientsBox.Columns.Add("Full name");
    CDB.ListClients(ListClientsBox.Items);
}
```

**Edit:**

I've run some tests, code you posted in comment seems to be fine. You might only need to adjust few ListView's properties, depending on display you aim for:

```
// perpare ListView beforehand
this.listView.Columns.Add("First name");
this.listView.Columns.Add("Email");
this.listView.Columns.Add("Country");
this.listView.View = View.Tile;
// if tile height is too small, some data might not be visible
this.listView.TileSize = new Size(180, 50); 

// sample data
var people = new[] 
{
    new { FirstName = "John", Email = "john@domain.com", Country = "USA" },
    new { FirstName = "Betty", Email = "betty72@mail.org", Country = "Canada" },
    new { FirstName = "Steven", Email = "stv@domain.net", Country = "Brazil" },
};

foreach (var person in people)
{
     ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(person.FirstName);
     item.SubItems.Add(person.Email);
     item.SubItems.Add(person.Country);
     this.listView.Items.Add(item);
}
```

And this is how ListView looks like, with both `View.Tile` and `View.Details`:
[image: ListView examples]

Comment: it does have columns set. what I want to do is a bit different from the example I posted. I want to use a list of objects and fill the listview like so:

Comment: foreach (SalesRecord s in sales)
            {
                Salesperson p = s.SalesPerson;
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(p.FullName);
                item.SubItems.Add(p.Email);
                item.SubItems.Add(p.Country);
                item.SubItems.Add(p.Phone);
                list.Add(item);

            }